# What does the word, “truth-up” mean?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, phrase-meaning, compounds

There was the following paragraph in the article titled “Welcome to the post-truth presidency” in [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/welcome-to-the-post-truth-presidency/2016/12/02/baaf630a-b8cd-11e6-b994-f45a208f7a73_story.html?utm_term=.540827ff583c) (December 2).

> “As Politico’s Susan Glasser wrote in a sobering assessment of
>   election coverage for the Brookings Institution, “Even fact-checking
>   perhaps the most untruthful candidate of our lifetime didn’t work; the
>   more news outlets did it, the less the facts resonated.” So there is
>   no reason to think Trump is about to suddenly **truth-up**. Indeed,
>   all signs are to the contrary — most glaringly Trump’s
>   chockfull-of-lies tweet that “I won the popular vote if you deduct the
>   millions of people who voted illegally.”

Though Google Ngram indicates that the word, “truth up” is current even before or since the beginning of the 19th century with its peak of usage in mid-1800s, neither Oxford nor Cambridge online dictionaries carry this word.

Does “truth up” mean to try to be more truthful and show integrity? What does “truth up” mean? Is it a popular word?

Comment: I think 'fess-up' is be a better choice of contemporary word usage than "truth up" [sic].

Comment: @PeterPoint I agree that "fess up" would be more common, but the general idea seems to be to play off the current popularity of the OD´s word-of-the -year _post-truth_ and truthiness.

Comment: +1, but is the origin really man/cowboy up? I always associate it with level-up or 1up (a.k.a. extra life), but maybe that's just stemming from my playing too many video games as a kid...

Comment: It's the opposite of "trump up".

Comment: Google Ngram does not indicate that "truth up" is a phrasal verb unit. It indicates that this pair of words occurs in some texts. For instance, a sentence like, "He didn't see the *truth up* to that point" contains a match.

Comment: It's regrettable that the verb *to true* doesn't seem to support reflexive usage in this case, as in "no reason to think he's about to true". To true something (verb, transitive) is to make it true: to make it accurate, straight, and so on. You can true a bicycle wheel, or a guitar fretboard,

Comment: @Kaz - The idiom "truth up" is almost certainly too recent to have been characterized by Ngram.

Answer (score 23):

The construction 'something up' is informal American usage, typically when encouraging, exhorting, or castigating someone.  Originally seen in "[man up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/man+up)" or "[cowboy up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cowboy+up)" (Free Dictionary), respectively meaning:

> to adopt a sufficiently resolute approach or course of action
>
> to adopt a tough approach or course of action

If I say to someone:

> You need to man up and finish your college degree

then I'm encouraging and challenging him to be tougher and to finish his studies.

So by extension, 'truth up' means to be more truthful.  The sentence you quoted could be written more formally as:

> So there is no reason to think Trump is about to suddenly become more truthful.

EDIT

There's another example, 'lawyer up', which means to get a lawyer involved in a problem.

> If your boss has been sexually harassing you, I advise you to lawyer up before you do anything else.

Comment: Lighten up on 'The Donald', please. Most of us on Planet Earth have caught up with the post-political transmutation of hyperbole in place of truth. I will be happy if 50% of all this BS (for BS we should now read 'Brilliant Strategy') comes to pass. Salutations!

Comment: @Peter Point. I have no intent to associate my question with politics at all. All the record of my 996 questions prove that. I'm not interested in the politics of any particular country. I'm simply asking the meaning of "truth up" and usage of 'noun + up' combination as a verb. It has nothing to do with Mr. Trump by person.

Comment: @YoichiOishi   Apologies for any perceived and/or unintended political association. I meant my comment to be read as a 'tongue in cheek' quip rather than a personal indictment. Point taken.

Comment: I would say "suit up," meaning to put on your uniform and equipment for a game, is one of the original uses of this form.

Answer (score 1):

The particle (or adverb) [*up*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up) is a very useful word to indicate

> with greater intensity

while [*down*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down) is used to indicate

> to a lesser degree, level, or rate

Truth-up means to *tell the truth with greater intensity* or *tell the truth more (one level up) compared with the past*. It also could be considered short for *take (bring) the truth up a notch*. The opposite would be *take (bring) the truth down a notch*.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that  the expression, **truth-up** is uncommon, *[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/truth)* doesn't contain any mention in its **truth** entry. The coined expression is really a clever play on words. Consider the ‘satirical’ title of the Washington Post   *‘Welcome to the **post-truth** presidency’*, it is evident that *truth-up* mirrors the word-of-the-year: *post-truth*. It also echoes the far more common and informal term **fess up**; [(*confess; own up*)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fess) which @PeterPoint in the comments [correctly pointed out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361896/what-does-the-word-truth-up-mean/361953#comment842205_361896).       <sub><sup>(I've been waiting months to pull off that pun)</sup></sub>

As @John Feltz explained in his answer, it means to be more truthful but I'll also add the following observation; it is almost demanding or wresting from the President elect, the truth.

Context
The President elect has been accused of  telling untruths  throughout his presidential campaign; however, despite normal expectations, the hour of reckoning is nowhere in sight.

Comment: OK, three downvotes. Would somebody care to explain what is wrong, or not useful about this answer?

Answer (score 0):

"Truth up" means to start telling the truth or be more truthful about one's intentions. There is an analogy to similar expressions (noun + "up") using the word "up" in the sense of "to cause (a level or amount) to be increased" such as "level up" (to advance to the next higher level) or, as in the case of "truth up," as an exhortation such as "man up" (be brave or tough enough to deal with an unpleasant situation), "cowboy up" (be more determined, try harder to overcome a difficult or adverse situation).

Comment: How do you know? Can you provide any supporting evidence, quotes, or references to support this answer? Please [edit] your answer to add that supporting information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "truth up" in this context means "become more truthful".

I think the antecedent people are looking for is the phrase ["buck up"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buck%20up) (Merriam-Webster):

> 1:  improve, smarten
>
> 2:  to raise the morale of

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buck+up%2Cfess+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuck%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfess%20up%3B%2Cc0) indicates that "buck up" has been more popular than "fess up". Also its meaning is closer to that of "man up" and "cowboy up".